# Extending error bound from scalar functions to vector functions

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, normed-spaces, sobolev-spaces

A commonly used results in finite element analysis states that:
$$
||u - u_h||_{q, \Omega} \leq C h^{\min (k+1,s)-q} |u|_{s, \Omega}
$$
for 'smooth enough' $u$ and the norm/seminorm is defined as (using multi-index notation):
$$
||v||_{H^s(\Omega)} = \left( \sum_{0 \leq {|\alpha|} \leq s} ||D^\alpha v||^2_{L^2(\Omega)} \right)^{1/2}
$$
$$
|v|_{H^s(\Omega)} = \left( \sum_{{|\alpha|}=s} ||D^\alpha v||^2_{L^2(\Omega)} \right)^{1/2}
$$
with the spaces defined as:
$$
H^1(\Omega) = \{ v \in L^2(\Omega): \nabla v \in (L^2(\Omega)^d \},
$$
where
$$
L^2(\Omega) = \{ v: \int_\Omega v^2 d\Omega < \infty \}.
$$
I wonder if the inequality at the top can be extended for vector functions? Like for $\mathbf{u} = \left(u_x, u_y, u_z \right)$?

Comment: Why not applying the scalar inequality to each of the vector components?

Comment: @daw so is it valid to say that, by applying to each vector component, i.e. $||u_x - (u_h)_x||_{q, \Omega} \leq C h^{\min (k+1,s)-q} |u_x|_{s, \Omega}$ (with subscript being the component not the derivative), we can arrive at $||\mathbf{u} - \mathbf{u}_h||_{q, \Omega} \leq C h^{\min (k+1,s)-q} |\mathbf{u}|_{s, \Omega}$?

Comment: yes, I think so.

Comment: I see. Feel free to turn this into an answer so I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\textbf{u}$ be a vector valued function such that $\textbf{u}:=(u_1,u_2,...,u_N)$ whose pointwise elements are members of $\mathbb{R}$. If a scalar valued function has the norm $||\cdot||$  We equip vector valued functions with the norm $||\textbf{u}||=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^N||u_i||^2}$. Therefore, your inequality becomes:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
||\textbf{u}-\textbf{u}_h||_{q,\Omega}&=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^N ||u_i-u_{h,i}||_{q,\Omega}^2}\\
&\leq \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^NC_i^2h^{2(\min(k+1,s)-q)}||u_i||_{s,\Omega}^2}\\
&\leq \sqrt{\sup_iC_i^2h^{2(\min(k+1,s)-q)}\sum_{i=1}^N||u_i||_{s,\Omega}^2}\quad \text{Since $h^{2(\min(k+1,s)-q)}$ is independent of $i$. }\\
&=Ch^{\min(k+1,s)-q}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^N||u_i||_{s,\Omega}^2}\quad \text{Taking $C=\sqrt{\sup_iC_i^2}$}\\
&=Ch^{\min(k+1,s)-q}||\textbf{u}||_{s,\Omega}
\end{split}
\end{equation}